# chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener is not responding

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

I saved a variable in key: data
Console.log(data.key), gives me out my data.

But now I send a message to the background.js from my popup.js and it doesnt read line:

```
sendResponse(data.key);
```

result = undefined, I tried to move it out of `chrome.storage.local.get("key", function(data) { })` and it worked with a test variable.

**Popup.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from: 'popup',subject: 'ubisoft'}, function (result) {

        window.alert(result)
        
      });
```

**Background.js:**

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender,sendResponse) => {

    // First, validate the message's structure.
    if ((msg.from === 'popup') && (msg.subject === 'ubisoft')) {
      // Enable the page-action for the requesting tab.
      chrome.storage.local.get("key", function(data) {
        // Do something with data.key
        console.log(data.key)
        sendResponse(data.key);
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Code within the callback of `chrome.storage` executes asynchronously; you need to inform Chrome that you will reply asynchronously by returning `true` from the message listener.